# what can i use instead of `case of` to reduce the code?

Tags: haskell, option-type

```
fmap ( \eachSheet -> case (eachSheet ^. sProperties) of
  Just sheetProperties -> case (sheetProperties ^. sTitle) of
    Just sheets -> (sheetProperties ^. sSheetId)    
    Nothing -> Nothing
  Nothing -> Nothing ) listOfSheets
```

any better way to this then case matching

Comment: There definitely are better ways to do this, but please make this an [MCVE] so we can actually see what it needs to do.

Comment: This is typically a Maybe *monad*.

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be `sheets ^. sSheetId`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, its correct

Comment: `fmap (_sProperties >=> \props -> _sTitle props >> _sSheetId props)` or something like it is probably what I would have written. Note that `_sTitle props >> ...` is a more specific instance of the useful idiom: `guard (somePredicate props) >> ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you here bascially show is the use of a `Maybe` *monad*, so we can write it like:

```
fmap (\s -> (s ^. sProperties) >>= \sheetProperties -> (sheetProperties ^. sTitle) >> (sheetProperties ^. sSheetId)) listOfSheets
```

Since a `Maybe` monad is defined as:

> ```
> instance Monad Maybe where
>     return = Just
>     (>>=) Nothing _ = Nothing
>     (>>=) (Just x) f = f x
> ```

Or we can write it in do notation, although that is basically the same:

```
fmap f listOfSheets
    where f eachSheet = do
        sheetProperties <- eachSheet ^. sProperties
        sheets <- sheetProperties ^. sTitle
        sheetProperties ^. sSheetId
```

Answer (score 8):

The particular pattern

```
     case f foo of
       Just bla -> case g bla of
          Just muh -> h muh
       Nothing -> Nothing
```

is chararacteristic of the *`Maybe` monad*. That instance is defined as

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  return = Just
  Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
  Just x >>= f = f x
```

So you can rewrite the above `case` construction to

```
    f foo >>= \bla -> g bla >>= \muh -> h muh
```

which can be made more readable by either using `do` syntax

```
    do
      bla <- f foo
      muh <- g bla
      h muh
```

or eta-reduction and the [Kleisli-composition operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-)

```
     (f >=> g >=> h) foo
```

In your example, the latter is actually not possible because the innermost function doesn't use `sheets` but `sheetProperties` again, but `do` notation can still be used.